# wcf client - soap encoding - complex types in different namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, xml-serialization, wcf-client

I keep running into namespace mismatches when trying to deserialize the SOAP response.

The response is unqualified and the nested complex types are qualified with a namespace like this:

```
<getResult>
<enc:ApplicationExceptionOccurred xmlns:enc="com.namespace1.www/complexTypes">false</enc:ApplicationExceptionOccurred>
<enc:SystemExceptionOccurred xmlns:enc="com.namespace1.www/complexTypes">false</enc:SystemExceptionOccurred>
<enc:ComplexType xmlns:enc="com.namespace1.www/complexTypes">
...
</enc:ComplexType>
</getResult>
```

I can get the namespaces correct by adding the following attribute to the generated types:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="com.namespace1.www/complexTypes", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Order=0)]
```

This works fine if the message is Literal.  However, this service uses SOAP encoding.  When I add the following to the XmlSerializerFormatAttribute:

```
 Use = System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded
```

Then the XmlElementAttributes appear to be ignored and I once again have namespace mismatch issues.  I presume that I need to use the SoapElementAttribute instead, but it does not have a way to set the namespace.

So...How can I set the namespace in a manner similar to XmlElementAttribute on Soap encoded messages?